# Table cell with multiple actions

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, action

How do I accomplish something like this: 
[a table cell with multiple actions inside the text](http://notfugly.com/app/xcode_so_tablecellquestion.png)
(link to image, since I don't have enough point to paste images)

I want to be able to control what the bold text does (e.g. activate a segue) and I also want the cell itself to have a separate action.

Is this possible? 
The text is dynamic, so the string lengths are not fixed.

Any help is much appreciated! (this is my first question of StackOverflow btw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel), it can handle multiple links inside text.

Comment: Thx, it looks promising. I will try it out and see if I can get it to do what I want!

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}


NSString *indexpath_str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row+1];

NSString *ordinary_string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is %d",indexPath.row+1];

NSMutableAttributedString *attri_str=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:ordinary_string];

int last=[indexpath_str length];
int begin=[ordinary_string length]-[indexpath_str length];



 [attri_str addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor yellowColor] range:NSMakeRange(begin,last)];
    [attri_str addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:30] range:NSMakeRange(begin, last)];





cell.textLabel.attributedText =attri_str;
return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your code and it makes it possible for me to style the text the way I want, but I don't understand how to attach an action to the the attri_str?

Comment: you can display, This strings to UITextView and make Textview to setEnable Links.

Comment: You can display this text to UIButton

Comment: NSMutableAttributedString *attri_str=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"HELLO"];
    
    
    
    [attri_str addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor yellowColor] range:NSMakeRange(2,2)];
    
    
    btn.titleLabel.attributedText=attri_str; // btn is UIButton

Comment: Thank you! - It's a good example of how to do it. I will try it out and see if it fits my needs.